# Using JSON.NET date format returned from a controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

In my MVC4 project I have a controller action as follows:

```
public ActionResult GetJson()
{
    var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now);
    return Json(DateTime.Now, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The response to the browser is in the old ASP.NET format:

> "/Date(1358987787691)/"

However, I know that MVC4 uses json.net by default, and that json.net uses ISO8601 format for dates.

In the code above, the serialized variable contains (what I want):

> "\"2013-01-24T13:39:12.7182079+13:00\""

Why is return Json(DateTime.Now) not (seemingly) using json.net?

I have also tried putting the following line in my global.asx:

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false;
```

but to no avail.

Comment: Seems I've misunderstood the documentation - json.net is the default json formatter for web API only.

Comment: The answer seems to be here: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could make some changes in controller factory and create your controller, which is inherited from standard controller, but used custom json formatter.